# Unable to log in as superuser on Django project

Tags: django

I am learning Django in order to create a small website, and I am still fairly new to coding.

I have an issue with the creation of superusers within the integrated Django admin module. I have followed the tutorials from OpenClassrooms, [SimpleIsBetterThanComplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/beginners-guide/1.11/) and tried to go through the official Django documentation but without success: **I am not able to log in as a superuser**

After I create a superuser, I cannot access the admin login page: http://localhost:8000/admin. I receive the following error:

> "Website is unaccessible. Localhost did not authorize the connection. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

and this interrupts my "python manage.py runserver" command.

I get the following in the CMD:

```
"GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
"GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
"POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
(env) C:\Users\Me\fmg3\fmg3\
```

If I delete the database from my project folder and apply migrations, I can access the /admin page again, so I guess that there is something wrong happening when I am creating the superuser, but then of course I cannot login anymore with the superuser created as I guess the credentials were in the database.

Below is the code of my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for fmg3 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = HIDDEN

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1']
# Added 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' after help from fuser60596

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'fmgapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'fmg3.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'fmg2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My urls.py file is as following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from fmgapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^home/', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

I have tried creating a new project with only one very simple view and everything as default, but still it doesn't work.
I create the superuser by activating the virtual environment and with the command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I use python 3.7.0 and Django 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this in your settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
```

and http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ should work.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!
I added 127.0.0.1 (and localhost as it was requested) to ALLOWED_HOSTS but the issue is still there. 

Thanks to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ I am now able to reach the login page again (I was using http://localhost:8000/admin/ before) but when I click "log in" then I get another connection error: 
"127.0.0.1 has not authorized the connection"

My runserver gets interrupted again then.

Comment: Vitors guide is for for Django 1.x and you are usungs Django 3.x and probably the guide is outdated anyway ( I did not looked into it in detail). Maybe you should start with the tutorial from the official Django homepage: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Session data and cookies for each host in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is stored *separately*, meaning that if you login to `http://localhost:8000/admin`, you **won't** be logged into `http://127.0.0.1/admin`.  You will need to re-authenticate for each host you want to use.

Also, I'd recommend using `path` instead of `url` in your `urlpatterns`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from fmgapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

The docs on [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#url):

> This function is an alias to django.urls.re_path(). It’s likely to be deprecated in a future release.